# Assigning percentages into categories in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a set of PERCENTRANK percentiles from excel for a value for about 5500 municipalities in Brazil, and I just want to convert them to easy to read categories that can be displayed on a map.

In this case, I'd like to field calculate a percentage of .098 to be in the category of '1', .198 to '2', and so forth.

Comment: TsvGis- Never thought of using symbology. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the unique values in the Symbology tab, select the range of values that you want to categorise (click the first value, hold down shift and then select the range of values), 
right mouse click and select group values.

[image]

Then in the label column, assign it the new catagory label e.g 2-3

[image]